# Building iphone project through script

Tags: iphone

Is is possible to build an iphone project by running an script?

Answer (score 0):

It most definitely is. Have a look at the `xcodebuild` command line tool. That'll let you build an xcode project from a script. It takes a few arguments so you can set the build configuration, which target to build, which sdk to use, etc.